# Specify Source IP for ADO connection from Delphi to MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, tcp, ado

My Delphi application is connecting to a MySQL database using tAdoConnection. 
My customer has a machine that has two connections to the database server through the network.  One is wired, the other wireless. So the machine running the application has two IP addresses on the same network.

My problem is that the wireless connection on this machine is not stable.  So I want to force the database connection to be made through the wired connection.  I know the source IP address that I want to use.

But how do I tell the ADO connection that it needs to connect through that source IP?

Comment: It is not possible to change that routing at ADOConnection. But you may have a look at this http://www.ezlan.net/metrics.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't need look for this feature inside ADO, this kind of task can be made using an external application which bind your ADO app to a specific network interface (or network connection). I've done this in the past using [`ForceBindIP`](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/).

Comment: But ... is it MY app that's creating the connection? If I'm interfacing with ADO, isn't the connection being made by something outside my app?

Comment: Your app ask the machine OS running on to connect to a special IP address. The OS is now responsible for getting the route to that IP address. If you want to change the route for your app you have to tell the OS to do so. It nearly the same, if you place a Button on your form, your app did not control the monitor to show the Button