# ADO .Net - How to specify source IP address in SqlConnection on system with multiple IP addresses

Tags: .net, sql-server, wcf, ado.net, asmx

I have server with a network adapter configured with multiple IP addresses. Different ASMX and WCF web services are installed on the server and for some security reason, for every WEB service i received from my network admins dedicated source IP address for connecting to specified RDBMS via ADO .Net. With lot of experiments I concluded that any SqlConnection object is connecting only via the first IP address configured on the network adapter (first IP address operate as a default source IP address).
Is there any way to specify source IP address for a SqlConnection object ?
I have already seen proposed solution for the similar problem at [Specify Source IP for ADO connection from Delphi to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727523/specify-source-ip-for-ado-connection-from-delphi-to-mysql) but that kind of solution is not applicable in my case.

I need something more similar to the way presented bellow that is used in case of ASMX web service clients, where I can specify source IP address via callback:

```
protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest webRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
    webRequest.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate += new System.Net.BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPointCallback);
    return webRequest;
}
private IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint sp, IPEndPoint epRemote, int tries)
{
    IPAddress ipLocal;
    EndPoint epLocal;
    IPAddress.TryParse(strIPAddr, out ipLocal);
    if (tries <= 3)
    {
        epLocal = new IPEndPoint(ipLocal, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("BindIPEndPointCallback: error connecting via {0}", strIPAddr));
    }
    return (IPEndPoint)epLocal;
}
```

Is there anything similar for a SqlConnection object ?

Comment: Why not just put the ip address in the connection string?

Comment: That would define destination IP address, not the source IP for connecting to RDBMS.

Comment: Only a comment.  Did you look at RouteTable Class?

Comment: System.Web.Routing.RouteTable as far as I know is a class for routing web requests namely in the MVC. I don't see how it can help me for SqlConnection?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any settings on the SQLConnection object to specify local IP.

However, you can set up a custom Windows Firewall rule to block the remote IP (SQL) for the source IPs (alternate network adapters).